# Como deixar de imprimir posições = 0 de um vetor?

Tags: c#, .net, array

No exemplo abaixo, como eu deixaria de imprimir as posições deste vetor que são igual a 0

```
int[] caluculo = {50,6,0,59,6,7,0,6,8};

for(int i = 0 ; i < 9 ; i++)
{    
    Console.WriteLine("{0}",calculo[i]);    
}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 5):

Sempre que precisa filtrar algo deve um `if`:

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < 9 ; i++) if (calculo[i] != 0) WriteLine(calculo[i]);
```

Ou pode fazer

```
foreach (var item in calculo) if (item != 0) WriteLine(item);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Array/Filter.cs).

Também pode usar LINQ, mas não acho que compense e é mais avançado.